# How to setup 2 Virtual Hosts on Apache where one host runs using SSL and other does not?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, vhosts, apache2.4

I am running Apache 2.4.18 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and PHP 5.6.18 on a physical Machine called SERVER1 and it is joined to my internal domain called `example.com`.

My Apache server by default have SSL turned on. I need to run 2 different sites where one site uses SSL and the other one does not.

Here is what I have added to my httpd-vhosts.conf file in attempt to get it to work

How can I get this to work?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName SERVER1.example.com
   Redirect permanent "C:/phpsites/app1" https://sub1.example.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:/phpsites/app2/public"
    ServerName SERVER1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub2.example.com

    SSLEngine Off

    <Directory "C:/phpsites/app2/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "C:/phpsites/app1"
    ServerName SERVER1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub1.example.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/certificate/cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/certificate/private.key"

    <Directory "C:/phpsites/app1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The setting above does not work properly. When I go to **https**://sub1.example.com Apache redirects me to the correct site C:/phpsites/app1. When I go to **http**://sub1.example.com it redirects me to C:/phpsites/app2/public but I don't want that to happen. And when I go to http://sub2.example.com I get redirected to **https**://sub1.example.com for some reason.

I need to direct any user that is looking for http://sub1.example.com or https://sub1.example.com to **https**://sub1.example.com.

And any users that is looking for http://sub2.example.com or https://sub2.example.com to go to **http**://sub2.example.com

Here is what I get when I execute `httpd -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

```
> VirtualHost configuration:
> 
> *:80 is a NameVirtualHost
> 
> 
> default server SERVER1.example.com
> (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:27) port 80 namevhost
> SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:27)
> 
> port 80 namevhost SERVER1.example.com
> (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:34) alias sub2.example.com
> 
> 
> *:443 is a NameVirtualHost default server SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:52) port 443 namevhost
> SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:52)
> alias sub1.example.com
> 
> port 443 namevhost SERVER1.example.com
> (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:85)
```

Answer (score 0):

My setting are actually working fine. For some reason Firefox is caching the dns in the browser.

I had to delete my temp file and everything worked like a charm!

It is bothering me and would like to know why would Firefox cache the dns!

I hope this note helps someone in the same boat!